# Groovy: How to load a properties file and deal with a "file not found" situation?

Tags: groovy

I am using the following code to load a properties file:

```
    File propertiesFile = new File(PROPS_FILE_PATH)
    Properties workflowProperties = new Properties()
    propertiesFile.withInputStream {
        workflowProperties.load it
    }
```

etc.

This works fine.
But I fail to handle a situation when the file does not exist.
What is the correct way to do that? 
Catching FileNotFoundException or any other exception did not work for me.

Thank you.

Comment: `File.exists()` didn't work either?

Comment: @injecteer You mean propertiesFile.exists() ?

Comment: yes, it's where your problem starts

Comment: Unfortunately cannot test it now, but in general, what would be propertiesFile value if the file does not exist? Wouldn't it be null?

Comment: no, you can create a `File` instance pointing to a non-existing file (usually used to create a new file). The only way to check it's existance is to call `.exists()`

Comment: @injecteer ok, thanks. I'll check and update asap

Comment: @injecteer Yes, it did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for file existence:

```
File propertiesFile = new File(PROPS_FILE_PATH)
if( !propertiesFile.exists() ) throw new Exception( 'File not found' ) // bail out
```

Comment: In Groovy, `if (!propertiesFile) throw new FileNotFoundException();` or simply `assert propertiesFile`. See http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html.